# how to use 'rsync --files-from' to avoid ssh's password repeatition?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

right now i'm using this code to syncronise stuff between my pcs:

```
nexus_ip=$(ip neigh | grep "nexus's mac addr" | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+')
function syncit () {
# rsync -rLEAXpogtP --delete "$1" "$2"
rsync -rulOHEAXpogtP --delete "$1" "$2"
}
while read source
    do
        destination=$nexus_ip:$(echo "$source" | grep -o '^.*/')
        syncit "$source" "$destination"
    done<<\_sources_list_
/.home/younes/.bashrc
/.home/younes/.bash_logout
/.home/younes/.bashrc.original
/.home/younes/.bash_aliases
/.home/younes/.profile
/.home/younes/.passwords
/.home/younes/.sh_history
/.home/younes/.python_history
/.home/younes/.how
/.home/younes/.kde/share/apps/yakuake/skins/younes
/.bin
_sources_list_
```

i googled about getting ride of ssh's password while using rsync over network and all what i get that i should use "--files-from" to give rsync a list , and that way i'll enter the password just one time !

*my problem is : how can i use --files-from ???*

if i put all sources in a file ! what about destinations ???

i'm really confused ! any one could show me an example according to my script's infos ? please

Comment: Would shared ssh keys work to remove the password requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run

```
ssh-copy-id user@server
```

so you will never have to enter the passwort again.

Before that, you will have to create a local key, which you can do by running

```
ssh-keygen
```